# List of figures alignment with caption over multiple lines

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, indentation, alignment

Currently there is a little "issue" in the list of figures as can be seen in the image below ("Figure 2"). If the caption text of the figure is to long for one line, the text is continued in a 2nd line but the 2nd line does not have the same indentation as the first line.

(How can I correct this?

The document class is "Article".

[image: LOF Alignment]

**UPDATE:** I use the commands below instead of `\listoffigures` to display the list of figures.

```
{% display "Figure 1", "Figure 2", etc.
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures%
}
```

Because I wanted the figures not to be listed simply with "1", "2", etc. (as was the case with `\listoffigures`) but with "Figure 1", "Figure 2", etc. With `\listoffigures` the indentation of a 2-line caption is correct but not with my used commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package which enables control of many aspects of the ToC, LoF and LoT layouts.

```
% lofprob.tex  SE 576535
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure } % put this before caption number
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4.5em} % increase space for augmented caption number

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering 
A FIGURE
\caption{Short caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering 
AN ILLUSTRATION
\caption{This is a long caption that will take up more than one line in the LoF}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful answer. A followup question arises here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/576651/231568). Maybe you can help here to.