# Change indentation within List of Figures (with tocloft package used)

Tags: lyx, indentation, tocloft

As suggested with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/576577/231568 I use `tocloft` to adjust the format of the list of figures. But as can be seen in the following picture (or also in the attachted picture of the above mentioned answer), there is a big indentation in the list of figures. There is no indentation within TOC and within the bibliography it seems that the spacing controlled with `\tabcolsep` is used.

How can I change/control the indentation in the list of figures?

[image: Lof Alignment]

Answer (score 0):

Use `\cftfigindent` to control the indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure } % put this before caption number
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0.5em} % change indentation of e.g. "Figure 1" within list of figures
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{4.5em} % increase space for augmented caption number

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering 
A FIGURE
\caption{Short caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering 
AN ILLUSTRATION
\caption{This is a long caption that will take up more than one line in the LoF}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```